# solution platforms selection

Tags: c++, visual-studio, platform

This may be a very silly question, but I am pretty sure nobody has asked this in stackoverflow.

When you build a C++ solution in Visual Studio, there are a couple of solution platforms you can choose, like Win32, X64, mixed platforms. I know that you may choose X64 if you want your program to be run by others in a X64 platform. My question is can you always choose mixed platforms which sounds to have included both Win32 and X64?

Comment: there is nothing called x32, probably you mean x86!

Comment: Oops, I meant Win32. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Well... Looks like there is similar post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702825/mixed-platform-vs-any-cpu