# Build configuration: Any CPU vs Mixed Platform

Tags: visual-studio, build, buildconfiguration

What is the difference among the following build configurations:

- Any CPU
- Mixed Platform

Note that this is a different question respect to [Build Configuration: Mixed Platform VS Any CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5702825/1288109) : there, according to the accepted answer, a suggestion is asked about what "build configurations settings" are, in a general sense; here I'm asking what the specific "Mixed platform" is intended for, and what's its difference respect to "Any CPU".

Thanks!

Comment: AnyCPU applies to a single assembly, but Mixed Platforms says you've got two or more assemblies that are configured to build differently in your solution (e.g., x86 for one and x64 for the other).  Apples and oranges.

Comment: Not sure. I have several projects in my solution, but they are all "Any CPU". The "Mixed Platforms" configuration appeared after I moved from a previous version of VS to VS 2015

Comment: Notice that you can't select "mixed platforms" in the Platform target combo in the build properties for a project?  Mixed platforms is the default solution platform name applied by vs.  I don't know the rules behind when and why it's created.  It doesn't really mean anything.  You can rename it http://i.stack.imgur.com/lqWms.png or change it to whatever. Why VS didn't use Any CPU in your case, I dunno.

Comment: "Previous version" matters a great deal.  They made a big mistake in VS2010 by having it create new projects with the x86 platform as the default.  Corrected again in VS2012.  If this is a pure managed solution then simply get rid of the bogus platform names.

Comment: Indeed, I just removed all configurations but "Any CPU" and my solution works just fine. I'm just wondering whether  "Mixed Platforms" has any real sense...