# What is .NET target platform in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, buildconfiguration

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5702825/13826315), it is discussed the difference between platform targeting in Visual Studio, I recently found that a **.NET** option was added there and these lines along others were added in the **sln** file.

```
Debug|.NET = Debug|.NET <---- Added
Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
Debug|Mixed Platforms = Debug|Mixed Platforms
Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
Release|.NET = Release|.NET <---- Added
Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
Release|Mixed Platforms = Release|Mixed Platforms
Release|x86 = Release|x86
```

These options are being added to each project in each solution I am opening recently.
I thought these options target a particular CPU architecture, AFAIK .NET is not one so what does its presence means?

Comment: I haven't seen a `.NET` option for platform for C# or C++ in Visual Studio. What type of project(s) are you working with? Is it possible that someone added a custom platform and named it `.NET`?

Comment: It is appearing is ASP.NET website and also VB.NET projects. Only me uses that computers, so I didn't add anything unless unintentionally, started appearing this week. I have VS 2022 17.8.2

Comment: Hmm. I couldn't reproduce using VS 2022 17.8.2. Is the .sln file version controlled? If yes, does the version history provide any clues? Is there tooling or an extension to the IDE that could have added the platform?

Comment: Yes, it is under TFS.  What was added compared to previous version is in the post.

Comment: I think it is a custom platform.